# twosided barplot with equal spaced quotient-values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a two-sided barplot where the distance of 2 from the center-line is the same as the distance of 0.5 on the opposite side (and from 5 is the same as 0.2 on the other side) - because the values represent quotients (preference or avoidance)
I tried it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(value=c(2, 0.5, 4, 0.25, 1, 0.3, 4,2, 3, 0.2 ,0.5, 0.4), group = rep(c("I","II","III"), 4), class = rep(c("a","b","c","d"), 3))

df$rez <-ifelse(df$value < 1,-( 1/df$value),df$value)
newlab <- c("1/5","1/4", "1/3", "1/2","1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

library (ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(class), rez, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5,5),breaks = c(-5, -4, -3, -2, 0,2, 3, 4, 5), labels = newlab)
p
```

But the spacing between the labels is not correct.

Comment: should it be? `c("1/5","1/4", "1/3", "1/2",0, "2", "3", "4", "5")`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The 1 is at the correct place, but the spaces between 1 and 2 and between 1 and 1/2 are wrong

Comment: Then you have to set your breaks accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

found a way; scale_y_log10() does the job:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(class, value, fill = group)) + geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
p +  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```